# Please give a classification of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology.

Tags: general-topology

I have learnt that there are three kinds of intervals in  $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology:the open interval, the closed interval and the semi open interval.

I think there are two classes of intervals in the lower limit topology:the right-closed interval and the right-open interval.But I fail to prove the closed interval is homeomorphic to the right-open interval and the open interval is homeomorphic to the right-closed interval.

Please show me a homeomorphism between these two intervals.(Especially please prove the map you give is a homeomorphism.)

Thanks for your help! I will be very grateful if you prove your given map is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

When $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the lower limit topology, there are two different classes of intervals up to homeomorphism, namely, the right-closed intervals and the right-open intervals.

First, we prove that all the right-closed intervals and right-open intervals are not homeomorphic.
For any right-closed intervals their right boundary point is an open set consisting of only one point $p$.
Suppose there is a homeomorphic $f$ between them, then $f(p)$ should be an open set.
However, for all the right-open intervals, a single point is not an open set.
That is a contradiction.

Then we intend to prove that there exist a homeomorphism inside each class.
It is straightforward to verify that all the open intervals are homeomorphic and all the left-closed right-open intervals are homeomorphic.
Therefore, to verify that all the right-open intervals are homeomorphic to each other, it suffices to prove that $(0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ are homeomorphic.
Define a sequence $\left\{x_n=1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a map
\begin{equation*}
        f:[0,1)\to(0,1),\quad f(x):= x-x_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\quad x\in[x_n,x_{n+1}).
    \end{equation*}
Note that $f$ is a homeomorphism.
For the case in right-closed intervals, we can define
\begin{equation*}
        f:[0,1]\to(0,1],\quad f(x):=\left\{
        \begin{array}{cl}
            x-x_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},  &  x\in[x_n,x_{n+1}),\\
            1,  &  x=1.
        \end{array}\right.
    \end{equation*}
This is a homeomorphic between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1]$.